# How do I add everyone on Facebook to Google+?

Tags: facebook, google-plus

Simple: how do I attempt to add all my Facebook friends to Google+

Comment: Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't make it easy to get your data out, and when it does it doesn't make it usable. Facebook also doesn't play well with Google. I was going to suggest a workaround with Yahoo! Mail, but they mark your contacts as being imported from Facebook and then won't let you export them (unless you visit and edit every single one).

Comment: Here is a [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Import-Your-Facebook-Friends-to-Google%2B) article on how to do it. tl;dr - it isn't easy to do, and nor is there an effective way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Your Facebook friends need to have a Google+ account first before you can add them. Even if they all have Google+, you can only added them manually one by one by visiting their Google+ account and add them to your circles manually.